# How to change border and icons in Search bar (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I have this:

http://postimg.org/image/ag29m3e7d/

and I need this

http://postimg.org/image/4bacislw5/

I have to create border or set it by image?
How to change search icons(magnifier and X icon) or could I change just colors?

Sorry for links but I cannot insert images here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To add borders use the views `layer` property.

```
self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

If you want to add the corner radius to the searchBar:

```
self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
self.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

To change the searchIcon call the following method on the searchbar:

```
self.searchbar.setImage(image, icon: UISearchBarIcon. UISearchBarIcon.Search, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

To change the cross:

```
self.searchbar.setImage(image, icon: UISearchBarIcon. UISearchBarIcon.Clear, state: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot. I have one last question, I have this nowhttp://postimg.org/image/oepn8hhzd/    , do you know how can I change height of search bar or how to make space between navigator bar line and search bar?

Comment: Have you changed the height?

Comment: What about changing the placeholder text color or placeholder test alignment? Also the search icon and placeholder text is center by default, how can we move it to be left or right justified?

Comment: for swift 4 : self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor and self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1

Answer (score 0):

For the border, select your UITextField in story board, then, in the attributes inspector, choose the border style.