# Custom searchBar with border

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, searchbar

Variations of this question have been asked before, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I've made the tableViewHeader the searchBar and this is what I have so far.

My code looks like this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureSearchBar()
    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.87, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0)
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

func configureSearchBar() {
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Companies"
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    //makes border for search box and gives color and rounded
    //searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.87, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    //searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    //searchController.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0

}
```

And I'm trying to build this but so far I have been unsuccessful

**What I am trying to build**

[image: Screen Shot]

If I try this:

```
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.87, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    searchController.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
    searchController.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

It ends up looking like this which is exactly what I am looking for.

**What it ends up looking like**

[image: Screen Shot]

Thank you for your help in advanced

Comment: You're more likely to get a helpful response if you post your current code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change border and icons in Search bar (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413127/how-to-change-border-and-icons-in-search-bar-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it to work like this. Instead of changing the size of the header what needed to be changed was the size of the textbox within the search bar.

```
func configureSearchBarTextField() {
    for subView in searchController.searchBar.subviews  {
        for subsubView in subView.subviews  {
            if let textField = subsubView as? UITextField {
                var bounds: CGRect
                bounds = textField.frame
                bounds.size.height = 35 //(set height whatever you want)
                textField.bounds = bounds
                textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                textField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                textField.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.87, blue:0.39, alpha:1.0).cgColor
                textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.cyan.cgColor
self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
self.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
```

and in the delegate update the height for the header:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}
```

Comment: That gave the search bar a border with rounded corners but it stays the same size as one of the cells and the top and bottom border are clipped to the top and bottom of the cell. Is there a way to change the height that might give me what I want?

Comment: Just change the height of the header then.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, but I can't figure it out. I'm a beginner, how do I do that?